# Axis averages for 2D plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a 3 dimensional data set (x, y, and a value - so effectively a gray-scale image) with matplotlib. I want to create a bar to the side of the plot with the average row-wise Y values, and a bar to the bottom with the average column-wise X values. The net result should be similar [scatter hist](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/scatter_hist_locatable_axes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-axes-grid1-scatter-hist-locatable-axes-py) (but instead of histograms on the side it is just a bar of color representing that particular row/column).

I have seen these plots before and would like to use one, I just can't figure out the name of the function.

Thanks for the help :)

i.e.

```
[1,2,3,4] |  [5
[4,3,2,1] |  5
[1,1,4,4] |  2.5]
----------
[2,2,3,3]
```

Comment: One possibility is to use `imshow` to plot the averages as narrow stripes next to your grayscale image - with the `extent` parameter you can define the coordinates where the stripe should appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to draw the images in different subplots. `xticks` in the main image are moved to the top, and removed from the right bar.

A test function is chosen to have identifiable features in both directions.

`vmin` and `vmax` are used to set the color range: image values at `vmin` get mapped to the lowest color (black-alike for the `inferno` colormap, or white for the `Greys` colormap), while image values at `vmax` get mapped to the highest color (yellow for `inferno`, black for `Greys`). Image values between `vmin` and `vmax` get gradually mapped to the colors inbetween.  Image values lower than `vmin` get mapped to the same lowest color.

It is important that the `vmin` and `vmax` for the 3 images is equal, so all three get the same color transformation. If `vmin`and `vmax` are not set, matplotlib calculates the lowest and highest value from the data. But the means typically have a smaller range of values, so corresponding values wouldn't be colored equally anymore.

Instead of setting `vmin` and `vmax`, a norm could be given. A [norm](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html) has a similar function, but is more powerful, for example when a logarithmic transformation is needed.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10, 10, 200), np.linspace(-10, 10, 200))
z = np.where((x < 7) & (y < 9), np.sin(x) + np.cos(y) ** 2, 2-np.cos(x) ** 2)

z1 = np.mean(z, axis=1).reshape(x.shape[0], 1)
z0 = np.mean(z, axis=0).reshape(1, x.shape[1])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(7, 7),
                         gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [10, 1], 'height_ratios': [10, 1], 'wspace': 0.1, 'hspace': 0.1})

vmin, vmax = -1, 2
cmap = plt.cm.inferno
extent=[-10, 10, -10, 10]

axes[0][0].imshow(z, cmap=cmap, extent=extent, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, aspect=1, origin='lower')
axes[0][0].xaxis.tick_top()

axes[0][1].imshow(z1, cmap=cmap, extent=extent, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, aspect=10, origin='lower')
axes[0][1].set_xticks([])
axes[0][1].yaxis.tick_right()

axes[1][0].imshow(z0, cmap=cmap, extent=extent, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, aspect=1 / 10, origin='lower')
axes[1][0].set_yticks([])

axes[1][1].axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example image]